# Unity 3D: Error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was coding AI for enemies in a game I’m making in Unity, but then Unity gave me this error. It says the error is on line 21, but I can't find it. Any help is appreciated!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float lookRadius = 10f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
    void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
{
    Gizmos.color = Color.red;
    Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, lookRadius);
}
```

Comment: you method OnDrawGizmosSelected is outside the EnemyController class, one of your curly braces is misplaced

Answer (score 0):

You have a closing bracket after the empty `Update()` function that doesn't belong there, it should be below `OnDrawGizmosSelected()` so that it encloses the `EnemyController` class as follows:

```cs
public class EnemyController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float lookRadius = 10f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, lookRadius);
    }
}
```